# How can I see React Native logs in the terminal?

Tags: ios, react-native

When running my React Native app in the iOS simulator and choosing "Debug JS Remotely" from the developer menu, I can see all my `console.log` statements in the Chrome developer tools just fine.  However, I've found that this is EXTREMELY slow -- it lags really bad and takes up a ton of memory.  I'd prefer to just see my logs in the terminal window.

Per [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#accessing-console-logs) I should just be able to run `react-native log-ios` but when I do that the only thing I see is:

```
$ react-native log-ios
Scanning 682 folders for symlinks in /Users/admin/Documents/projects/xxx/node_modules (8ms)
NOTE:  Most system logs have moved to a new logging system.  See log(1) for more information.
$diagnosticd[52162] <Notice>: dispatch_io_write error: 89 (Operation canceled)
$diagnosticd[52162] <Notice>: reflect channel created for fd 5
$budd[66301] <Error>: objc[66301]: Class BYBuddyDaemonCloudSyncClient is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SetupAssistant.framework/SetupAssistant (0x10aba8820) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SetupAssistant.framework/budd (0x10a6911f8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
$diagnosticd[52162] <Notice>: dispatch_io_write error: 32 (Broken pipe)
--- last message repeated 1 time ---
```

And none of my logs actually show up.

EDIT: for those familiar with `create-react-native-app` and Expo, that is exactly how I want my logs to appear.

Comment: You can the app through Xcode to see terminal output also? This usually seems 'faster'

Comment: Yeah, I think I've seen it in there before, but I actually have all of my logs color coded using [this trick](http://jafrog.com/2013/11/23/colors-in-terminal.html) so that debug vs trace vs warnings vs errors are easier to spot and this doesn't show up in Xcode.  Plus I actually switch between iOS and Android a lot and would prefer not to have to run Xcode and Android Studio.

Comment: Try `react-native-log-ios` npm package instead